# form.save wont save data and no rows added to database

Tags: python, django

I have a model as model below:

```
class ProductLeastDiscountLog(LoggableModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, verbose_name='a', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='least_discount_log')
n_weeks = models.IntegerField('a', null=True, blank=True)
    buy_price = models.BigIntegerField('a a', null=True, blank=True)
    future_sell_price = models.BigIntegerField('a a', null=True, blank=True)
    mean_sell_prediction = models.IntegerField('a a a a a', null=True, blank=True)
    discount_factor = models.FloatField('a a a', null=True, blank=True)
    least_discount = models.FloatField('a a a', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to use a model to add objects of this model to DB:

```
class LeastDiscountForm(BaseModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ProductLeastDiscountLog
    fields = ('n_weeks','buy_price', 'future_sell_price', 'mean_sell_prediction', 'discount_factor')
```

but after calling form.save db is still empty:

```
def action_view(self, http_request, selected_instances):
    if http_request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.modelForm(http_request.POST, http_request.FILES, instance=selected_instances[0],
                              http_request=http_request)
        print('let me see if form is vaid')
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')
            form.save()
            form = None
    else:
        form = self.modelForm(instance=selected_instances[0], http_request=http_request)

    return render(http_request, 'manager/actions/add_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title': self.form_title})
```

Comment: Your form needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm` not `BaseModelForm`

Comment: I changed it the way you said, it raise this error : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'http_request'
@IainShelvington

Comment: You should be passing http_request to the form

Comment: still not saving new row @IainShelvington

Comment: why you want http_request in your form?

Comment: I have removed http_request but still, no new row added to my DB. @vorujack

Answer (score 0):

you must change your Form like this:

```
class LeastDiscountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductLeastDiscountLog
        fields = ('n_weeks','buy_price', 'future_sell_price', 'mean_sell_prediction', 'discount_factor')


...


def action_view(self, http_request, selected_instances):
    if http_request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.modelForm(http_request.POST, http_request.FILES, instance=selected_instances[0])
        print('let me see if form is vaid')
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')
            form.save()
            form = None
    else:
        form = self.modelForm(instance=selected_instances[0])
    return render(http_request, 'manager/actions/add_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title': self.form_title})
```

form must be child of ModelForm not BaseModelForm. and you can not pass extra argument to initialize of form (http_request)

Comment: I did so, but the problem remained and nothing have been saved.